# C interpretation of a double

Tags: c, double, scanf

I am currently working on a project for school and I have been stopped by a problem. Basically what the assigment is: we get a file containing for instance: e 18.91, n 10.03 without the dot so there are all these values, 26 days, that display how frequently a letter is used.

What I need to do is use fscanf to sort these files. I want one containing the char and the other one I want the number. I have been trying the following thing:

```
fp2 = fopen("frequencyTable.txt", "r");
if(fp2 != NULL) {
    while (fscanf(fp, "%c %d", &currentLetter[counterTwo], &freqLetter) == 2){
        printf("%c AND %d\n", currentLetter[counterTwo], freqLetter);
        counterTwo++;
    }   
    exit(0);
}
```

But as I noticed the fscanf I am implementing is not see the second part of the number, so right side from the dot, as a double therefore stopping the loop. Is there anything I am missing out? What I should get is first the letter, so currentLetter, and second the whole number instead of breaking the loop and getting half a number

Does anyone has a clue or hint for me where to look specifically. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `%lf` format specifier for `double`

```
fscanf(fp, "%c %lf", &currentLetter[counterTwo], &freqLetter)
//              ^^
```

Comment: Thanks you are a lifesaver, thought I already tried it! Works now. Thank you so much again, was about to give it up

Comment: Could you explain me please how you fixed my code box, the top line was not lined out wel, so I wont make the same mistake in the future when posting something :)

Comment: Lines that start with 4 spaces are treated as code by default.  You can also highlight a block of text and use ctrl+k

Comment: @KiptScriddy I've just found a post on meta which better explains [how to format code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

> e 18.91, n 10.03 **without the dot**

You will have to `fscanf` the lines, go through it with a pointer and replace the second space with a dot, then use `sscanf` on that string.